# How to move from basic to modern authentication in my existing CSOM powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, authentication, scheduled-tasks

I have a big CSOM powershell script which is using basic authentication. This script is scheduled to run every day. This script is using credentials of a serviceaccount without MFA. We would like to disable basic authentication, but this script needs to be modified. I dont want to rewrite the whole CSOM script to Office Dev PnP Powershell because it is a big script.

What is the easiest way to move from basic to modern authentication in a CSOM powershell script?

See below a small part with authentication and some SPO logic:

```
$lo_ClientContext             = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext( https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/test )
$lo_ClientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials( myserviceaccount@mycompany.com, myPassword )
$lo_ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$ll_Lijst = $lo_ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle( "myList" )
$lo_ClientContext.Load( $ll_Lijst )
$lo_ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Please who can help me?

Comment: Sorry this isn't an answer but I dont have the reputation to comment. I have the same problem. I've checked and setting up Modern/Basic Authentication is Organisation wide. I.e. its not possible to create a new account allowing legacy connections. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way. Make a new account that allows legacy connections, disable MFA for it, and only turn it on before the script is ran, and then turn it off after.

It's a workaround, but likely easier than updating all your scripts to use azure app keys

Comment: Hi, this script is not for only run it one time. It will be scheduled to run every day.